# How to count TD that are inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code I am running but aint work. I am wondering why not. I am trying to count the number of TD I have in a DIV. Here bellow the code I am trying. I get the number of TD if I check for the whole row(TR). Help please I am stack.

Also I would like to know if there is a way to start counting these TD from the second or x child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Count TDs
  var Divcounter = $("#Div_TDs td").length;
  var Totalcounter = $("#total_TDs td").length;
  var result = $(".result");

  if (Totalcounter > 0) {
    result.html("They are <b>" + Divcounter + "</b> TDs in DIV </n>"); //Get Number of TD in DIV
    result.html("They are <b>" + Totalcounter + "</b> TDs in total! </n>");
  }
});
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th id="tblCol1">First</th>
      <th id="tblCol2">Second</th>
      <th id="tblCol3">Third</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="total_TDs">
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <div id="Div_TDs">
        <td>Charles</td>
        <td>Mike</td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="result"></div>
```

The number of TD for the whole row is the only code that will appear.

Comment: [`<td>` may only reside directly inside `<tr>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). Your markup is **highly invalid**

Comment: is there any other way one can count only those two TDs?

Comment: @Givenmasheka add specific class to those TDs you want to be able to count separately.

Comment: why did you place the `td` elements inside `div`s?

Comment: @vsync I added the div to be able to count those TDs separately

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
$(() => {
  console.log("Total: "+$("#total_TDs td").length)
  console.log("Special: "+$("#total_TDs td.special").length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th id="tblCol1">First</th>
        <th id="tblCol2">Second</th>
        <th id="tblCol3">Third</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr id="total_TDs">
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="special">Charles</td>
        <td class="special">Mike</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```